# Use foo->detect is wrong but use (*foo).detect is OK

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to some code like this(C++14):

```
std::unique_ptr<Face> foo;  
const auto boxes = foo->detect(image);
```

but the Android Studio Report an error like：

> applying -> operator to "std::unique_ptr" instead of pointer

if I use :

```
std::unique_ptr<Face> foo;  
const auto boxes = (*foo).detect(image);
```

There is no error,Why?Thanks for your answer.

Besides,someone No problem with the first method just use Clang without Android Studio.
I use Android Studio 3.1.4 with ndk 18 ,Cmkae 3.6.4

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing that last sentence. To clarify: the code in the first sample builds fine, but Studio complains about it? That wouldn't surprise me that much if that's the case. The CLion C++ parser often trips over anything mildly exotic (which the STL is full of). You could file a bug at http://b.android.com and they'll try to get it fixed.

Comment: @DanAlbert It's a BUG and after updated to Android 3.2.0 ,it is fixed.Thanks